# Java Buttons printing to seperate window

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is a way to write a Java GUI where when you press the buttons and the text will be printed on another window. For example, there could be a set of six buttons and one might say hello world and when pressed the output is printed to another window in its text field. Kind of like have shortcut keys in the GUI to print out messages. I have researched this but with no luck.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the same basic idea is getting notified when a button is pressed normally and notifying a different class that the event occured.  The actual implementation would depend greatly on the framework you wanted to use, but it's just basically a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Comment: So basically it would be like HotKeys but within a java program. I looked up the java example with the Hello world printing to console but when built it prints no where visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use swing, there are a lot of solutions. One of them is create a new frame and pass your value to new frame. [Example here](http://www.javaquery.com/2010/11/how-to-pass-variable-values-between.html)

Comment: And if it's HTML? JavaFX? SWT? GWT?  If you're going to try and answer this question, then you're going to have to provide possible implementations for all the possible frameworks.  I'd suggest making it a comment until we can get clarification of the actual framework the OP is using. *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can create two classes in the same package, and make them the way you want(for example; putting jlabels,textAreas,jButtons, etc.). Then, in the first class(the class with buttons), create an instance of second class. I mean

```
public class Class1 extends JFrame {
    public Class2 obj = new Class2();
```

then in the anonymous class(event class), make what you want (e.g. getting texts, setting text, etc.) and call your second class's frame and make it visible here. Something like that;

```
obj.txt.setText(textObj.getText());
obj.frame.setVisible(true); //it's important, if you don't set it visible you cannot see a new screen
```

So it opens a new screen and you see the text you entered in the first class. I think you want something like this. If it is not clear, I can put an example code here.